# Can I compile a Haskell project in release mode with Stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I wonder, isn't there a way to compile a Haskell project in release mode with Stack? There's no nothing related to "release" in `stack --help`. How can I compile it in Release mode then?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no such thing as "release mode".  Perhaps you want to enable more optimization?  In that case, pass in `--ghc-options -O2`.  Alternatively, add `-O2` to `ghc-options:` in your cabal file.  Then, you can use `stack build --fast` to override this with `-O0` which will build faster but optimize less.

Comment: can I pass --ghc-options -O2 to stack build? or only to cabal?

Comment: @OskarK. Why not check out [Stack's documentation](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#flags-and-ghc-options)?